# Import Product with AIF

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I'm trying to import some products via the AIF when using AX 2012. If I don't set the default purchase/sales/invent site and location, it works fine, but when I try to set them I get the following exception thrown:

```
Cannot create a record in Item purchase order settings (OST). 
The record already exists.
Error found when validating record.
Cannot edit a record in Item purchase order settings (InventItemPurchSetup). Item number: 
1472, 00000002_078.
The record already exists.
```

The item I am trying to upload has an ItemId of 1472, hence why it is in the exception

Here is the code (I will just show the Purchase setup as the Sales and Invent are pretty much the same):

```
            inventTable[0].InventItemPurchSetup = new[] { 
                new AxdEntity_InventItemPurchSetup {  
                    ItemId = inventTable[0].ItemId,
                    InventDimPurchSetup = new[] {
                        new AxdEntity_InventDimPurchSetup
                        {
                            InventDimId = "AllBlank2"
                        }
                    },
                    DefaultInventDimPurchSetup = new[] {
                        new AxdEntity_DefaultInventDimPurchSetup
                        {
                            InventDimId = "AllBlank2",
                            InventSiteId = "OST"
                        }
                    }
                },
                 new AxdEntity_InventItemPurchSetup {  
                    ItemId = inventTable[0].ItemId,
                    InventDimPurchSetup = new[] {
                        new AxdEntity_InventDimPurchSetup
                        {
                            InventSiteId = "OST"
                        }
                    },
                    DefaultInventDimPurchSetup = new[] {
                        new AxdEntity_DefaultInventDimPurchSetup
                        {
                            InventLocationId = "PER"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with AIF but today, curiously, I'm doing exactly the same thing with the Data Import Export framework (DMF).

My use case is the following:

- Run the DMFProductEntity to creates a Product which is visible across all companies, and will then 'release' the product creating your item (InventTable) with Inv/Purch/Sales setup configuration in the the selected company.
- Run the DMFInventTableEntity to then 'release' your product for other companies.  Part of this process, however, calls the *EcoResProductReleaseManager::release* product functionality that automatically creates the Inv/Purch/Sales setup configuration for you...  Now when DMF tries to insert these tables from it's own datasource it can generate the same  error as above.

In your case then, perhaps the *InventItemPurchSetup* type entities are already created, and you need to comment out in your code those like 'AllBlank' which can be created by default.

**OR** you are breaking the index above attemtping to insert the 'AllBlank2' InventDimId twice. The key for the *InventItemInventSetup* table are the *ItemId* and *InventDimId* fields.

**OR** the *InventLocationId = "PER"* is using the '00000002_078' *InventDimId* value which already exists.